# 401 when using client_credentials auth flow

Tags: fhir-server-for-azure

Everything works great with Postman and authorization_code grant. But I am trying to connect to FHIR with client_credentials flow, meaning no UI.

I am calling the url https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxx-c9a9-4be5-a9f7-xxxxxxxxxxxx/oauth2/v2.0/token with the parameters:

```
grant_type: client_credentials
client_id: [my fhir application ID]
scope: https://[myCompany].azurehealthcareapis.com/.default
client_secret: [mySecret]
```

With that, I get back a token

```
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 3599,
    "ext_expires_in": 3599,
    "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6Im5PbzNaRHJPRFhFSzFqS1doWHNsSFJfS1hFZyIsImtpZCI6Im5PbzNaRHJPRFhFSzFqS1doWHNsSFJfS1hFZyJ9.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.QMHS5OoWYflq30owYolvwzDkRJm4sG29G11Z_Qct_pPuj_ULm6hR4vC_jydqsq7eDFGxA1wb_Y8hJXVKTHBu1ij9_SKSlKhNZ6KmkqrvOhTaADFGw36albKNgII_xzA-gmeAOKQuKX9Q9wZmPfJETx5NJuJnG1qAnexvhQkhMv8AgiznnU9VbaIoAAvObHx9E5Pb5nesSmOhVwMxZRjBrTHqz9ryFUDYq3Pciuz6HvVF7ro9IijUg9d8r2da8HuXGXvZiJXkfiEW6OuR1RLv9QDol6WjAOKTB12q07iFFgDL0UTinWLY--3dn0raVyd7ZtT_yzLNRZ9iqX_XXXXX"
}
```

Now when I call the url https://[myCompany].azurehealthcareapis.com/Patient I get 401 response.

```
{
    "resourceType": "OperationOutcome",
    "id": "114e91311cbd11458e3d3284db6c9826",
    "issue": [
        {
            "severity": "error",
            "code": "login",
            "diagnostics": "Authentication failed."
        }
    ]
}
```

This is what I have for Api Permissions

[image]

Comment: Can you update your post with the full request to https://[myCompany].azurehealthcareapis.com/Patient ? If you were getting "code: forbidden", I'd say look at the FHIR RBAC configuration (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/healthcare-apis/fhir/configure-azure-rbac), but the "code: login" suggests the access_token isn't being accepted (even though the claims look fine in token.payload).

Comment: @rmharrison For the /Patient, there is no configuration other than the Authorization header and the Bearer token. I am using Azure RBAC and I feel like I am missing something between App Registration and my Fhir service. Something like I need to give access rights to the Api Services I have configured. Using RBAC I try and search for Fhir-Service-Client, but its not in the directory. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/healthcare-apis/fhir/register-service-azure-ad-client-app.

Comment: I updated my Api Server so the API url matches the Fhir url https://[myCompany].azurehealthcareapis.com, and now I get a 403 - forbidden. Its differentm i guess.

Answer (score 0):

On the Fhir service, select Access control (IAM) from the left menu (if you are using Azure RBAC).

[image]

From there, click on Role Assignments

[image]

Then search for your your App Registration

[image]

This allows your app to have permissions to the Fhir service outside of that of the logged in users.